# Pandas split name column into first and last name if contains one space

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame containing names like so:

`name_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Jack Fine','Kim Q. Danger','Jane Smith', 'Juan de la Cruz']})`

```
    name
0   Jack Fine
1   Kim Q. Danger
2   Jane Smith
3   Juan de la Cruz
```

and I want to split the `name` column into `first_name` and `last_name` IF there is one space in the name. Otherwise I want the full name to be shoved into `first_name`.

So the final DataFrame should look like:

```
  first_name     last_name
0 Jack           Fine
1 Kim Q. Danger
2 Jane           Smith
3 Juan de la Cruz
```

I've tried to accomplish this by first applying the following function to return names that can be split into first and last name:

```
def validate_single_space_name(name: str) -> str:
    pattern = re.compile(r'^.*( ){1}.*$')
    match_obj = re.match(pattern, name)
    if match_obj:
        return name
    else:
        return None
```

However applying this function to my original name_df, leads to an empty DataFrame, not one populated by names that can be split and Nones.

Help getting my current approach to work, or solutions invovling a different approach would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `str.split` to split the strings, then test the number of splits using `str.len` and use this as a boolean mask to assign just those rows with the last component of the split:

```
In [33]:
df.loc[df['name'].str.split().str.len() == 2, 'last name'] = df['name'].str.split().str[-1]
df

Out[33]:
              name last name
0        Jack Fine      Fine
1    Kim Q. Danger       NaN
2       Jane Smith     Smith
3  Juan de la Cruz       NaN
```

**EDIT**

You can call `split` with param `expand=True` this will only populate where the name lengths are exactly 2 names:

```
In [16]:
name_df[['first_name','last_name']] = name_df['name'].loc[name_df['name'].str.split().str.len() == 2].str.split(expand=True)
name_df

Out[16]:
              name first_name last_name
0        Jack Fine       Jack      Fine
1    Kim Q. Danger        NaN       NaN
2       Jane Smith       Jane     Smith
3  Juan de la Cruz        NaN       NaN
```

You can then replace the missing first names using `fillna`:

```
In [17]:
name_df['first_name'].fillna(name_df['name'],inplace=True)
name_df
​
Out[17]:
              name       first_name last_name
0        Jack Fine             Jack      Fine
1    Kim Q. Danger    Kim Q. Danger       NaN
2       Jane Smith             Jane     Smith
3  Juan de la Cruz  Juan de la Cruz       NaN
```

Comment: This is close, but isn't quite right. I need name to just be 'Jack' if there is one space, not 'Jack Fine'. I'm working on figuring this out...

Comment: Very cool, thank you! I actually just got it to work in a more verbose way, so I appreciate the elegance of your solution.

Comment: With your edited solution I get `ValueError: Colunns must be same length as key`

Comment: @Nisba sorry but answering questions in comments is counter-productive. You need to post an actual question with your data, code to reproduce your df, the desired result, your attempts, and any errors

Comment: @EdChum ok I understand. Anyway, I solved my problem using the solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601397/split-a-pandas-column-into-two-based-on-a-delimiter-that-may-not-exist-on-all-va

Answer (score 1):

I was having some issues with `IndexError: list index out of range` because the names could be `test`, `kk` and other weird user input. So ended up with something like this:

```
items['fullNameSplitLength'] = items['fullName'].str.split().str.len()
items['firstName'] = items['lastName'] = ''
items.loc[
  items['fullNameSplitLength'] >= 1,
  'firstName'
] = items.loc[items['fullNameSplitLength'] >= 1]['fullName'].str.split().str[0]
items.loc[
  items['fullNameSplitLength'] >= 2,
  'lastName'
] = items.loc[items['fullNameSplitLength'] >= 2]['fullName'].str.split().str[-1]
```